# How to use Datasource configured in WSO2 BPS

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2 family (`WSS, ESB & BPS`).
Previously I did samples on creating `datasource` in `WSO2 ESB` and I have retrieved data from datasource using `DBLookup` in `WSO2 ESB`.
Now I have configured datasource in `WSO2 BPS(from UI)` and it is successfully connected to the database.
How Can I use the datasource that I configured in BPS in `BPEL Workflow`?
Please someone guide through it.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the doucumentation[1] which shows how to define a datasource and refer [2] which shows how to configure datasource in bps.xml

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BPS300/Adding+RDBMS+Data+Sources#AddingRDBMSDataSources-jndi

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BPS300/ODE+Configurations#ODEConfigurations-DataSource

Comment: Thanks Lakmali. I have defined my datasource already as in link [1]. My question is, How to use it in `BPEL` workflow? i.e. Where should I write the query using that Datasource? Any tutorial is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better approach would be to use WSO2 Data Services Server and create Data Service using the data source. (You can define the data source in Data Services server). After that you can call them using the BPS. Please refer following tutorial on such a comprehensive tutorial.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DVS300/Retail+Banking+Sample

Comment: Thanks Shelan. As of now I am following the above approach that you mentioned already. But I wonder, if we are unable to write a query in BPEL, then what is the need for Datasource defined in it?